# Javascript assigning value to primitive

Tags: javascript

If JavaScript will readily coerce between primitives and objects why adding properties to it results to undefined??

```
var a = "abc";
var b = a.length
console.log(b)//outputs 3
```

Does coercion allow me to assign values to primitives?If not why ?

Comment: I think what you're actually asking is **'Does coercion allow me to assign values to primitives' properties?'**, not the primitives themselves. Same goes for the @Maizere's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> Does coercion allow me to assign values to primitives?

Yes. The primitive is wrapped in an object, and a property is created on that. No exception will be thrown.

> why adding properties to it results to undefined?

The adding itself does result in the value.

```
var str = "abc";
console.log(str.someProperty = 5); // 5
```

Yet, what you're asking for is getting a property from a primitive. This will return in `undefined` since the primitive is wrapped in a **new** wrapper object - not the one which you assigned the property on:

```
console.log(str.someProperty); // undefined
```

It only works for special properties like `.length` that are created with the object, or inherited ones like `slice` or `charAt` methods (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_instances) for those).

If you wanted such a thing, you'd need to create the wrapper object explicitly and store it somewhere:

```
var strObj = new String("abc");
strObj.someProperty = 5;
console.log(strObj.someProperty); // 5
// coercion and the `toString` method will even make the object act like a string
console.log(strObj + "def"); // "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
var abc=Number(3);
abc.foo="bar";

abc; //3
abc.foo; //bar
```

@Bergi indeed, sorry for this. I've missed the `new` statement. Here it is:

```
var abc=new Number(3);
abc.foo="bar";

abc; //3
abc.foo; //bar
```

At least it works just right. I don't know what else someone may need :)
primitives... coercion... blah.